# Original error:An server-side error occurred while processing the command.Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'

Tags: google-chrome, appium-android

I am getting the following while I am trying to launch the chrome browser in the android device. 
    I have installed the chrome version packages in the npm.

Original error: A server-side error occurred while processing the command.Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'

```
Following are the appium logs

[debug] [Chromedriver] Found Chrome bundle 'com.android.chrome' version '80.0.3987'
[Chromedriver] Error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
[Chromedriver]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:79:13)
[Chromedriver]     at Chromedriver.errorAndThrow [as getCompatibleChromedriver] (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:366:13)
[Chromedriver] Error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
[Chromedriver]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:79:13)
[Chromedriver]     at Chromedriver.errorAndThrow [as start] (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:540:11)
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/bc9ecbe6-e4be-49a1-b8ef-ef982a549310] with no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"bc9ecbe6-e4be-49a1-b8ef-ef982a549310","value":null}
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200
[debug] [ADB] Running 'F:\workspace\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 42003a0fd361847b forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1581572581378 (11:13:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
[debug] [W3C]     at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:79:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at Chromedriver.errorAndThrow



Following are the logs on the ide

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'MONA-WIN-PUNE', ip: '192.168.1.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'MONA-WIN-PUNE', ip: '192.168.1.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
    at ChromeLaunchBase.capabilities(ChromeLaunchBase.java:28)
    at ChromeBrowser.main(ChromeBrowser.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'MONA-WIN-PUNE', ip: '192.168.1.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers download server feature
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Mona\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 19 more

class I have created

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class ChromeBrowser extends ChromeLaunchBase {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>driver = capabilities();
    driver.get("http://facebook.com");
}

}

======================================
capabilities I have set
====================================
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class ChromeLaunchBase {

public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException  {


        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        /*caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "AppiumTutorial");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"uiautomator2");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");*/

        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "42003a0fd361847b");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.1.0");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/Mona/Desktop/chromedriver55.exe");
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
        return driver;
    }

}


============================
installed chrome with the following: 
npm install appium chromedriver_version="2.46"
```

Original error:An server-side error occurred while processing the command.Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '80.0.3987'

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to start the appium server with this command and it will get the matched Chromedriver version:

```
appium --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the steps in [this link](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/), as it has a full description of how to run a browser instance on android devices.

Simply put, you should install the driver using this command:

```
npm install appium --chromedriver_version="2.16"
```

Then start the appium server with this command:

```
appium --chromedriver-executable /path/to/my/chromedriver
```

Consider the version of Chrome Browser on your mob device.